# Compare strings using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I've got a homework assignment that I just can't figure out. I have to write a static method match(String x, String y) that returns a boolean for whether or not string x and string y match. The matching process should allow "wild cards" such as '@' character which will match with any single character and the '*' character which will match with 0 or more characters of any type. I'm not allowed to use any loops and I have to use recursion.
What I've written so far is this...

```
public class CompareStrings {
public static boolean match(String x, String y) {
    if (x.length() <= 1 && y.length() <= 1) {
        if (x.equals("*") || y.equals("*")) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((x.length() == 1 && y.length() == 1) && (x.equals("@") || y.equals("@"))) {
            return true;
        }
        return  x.equals(y);
    }
    String x1 = "";
    String x2 = "";
    String y1 = "";
    String y2 = "";
    if (x.length() == 0 && y.charAt(0) == '*') {
            y2 = y.substring(1, y.length());
    }
    if (y.length() == 0 && x.charAt(0) == '*') {
            x2 = x.substring(1, x.length());
    }
    if (x.length() > 1 && y.length() > 1) {
        if (x.length() != y.length() && !x.contains("*") && !y.contains("*")) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x.charAt(0) == '*') {
            x1 = "*";
            x2 = x.substring(1, x.length());
            y1 = "*";
            y2 = y.substring(y.length()-x2.length(), y.length());
        }
        else if (y.charAt(0) == '*') {
            y1 = "*";
            y2 = y.substring(1, y.length());
            x1 = "*";
            x2 = x.substring(x.length()-y2.length(), x.length());
        }
        else {
            x1 = x.substring(0, 1);
            x2 = x.substring(1, x.length());
            y1 = y.substring(0, 1);
            y2 = y.substring(1, y.length());
        }
    }
    return match(x1, y1) && match(x2, y2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(match("hello", "hello.") + " 1 false"); // should return false
    System.out.println(match("hello", "jello") + " 2 false"); // should return false
    System.out.println(match("hello", "h@llo") + " 3 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("hello", "h@@@@") + " 4 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("hello", "h*") + " 5 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("hello", "*l*") + " 6 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("anyString", "*") + " 7 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("help", "h@@@@") + " 8 false"); // should return false
    System.out.println(match("help", "h*") + " 9 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("help", "*l*") + " 10 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("help", "*l*p") + " 11 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("help", "h@llo") + " 12 false"); // should return false
    System.out.println(match("", "*") + " 13 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("", "***") + " 14 true"); // should return true
    System.out.println(match("", "@") + " 15 false"); // should return false
    System.out.println(match("", "") + " 16 true"); // should return true
}
```

}

The main method is the test program given by the assignment. I realize my code is a little messy - I was scrambling a bit - but I can seem to get most of it working. The only example that doesn't return the right value is number 11. I get false when it should be true. The reason I think this is happening is because since the string y starts with a '*', the thing my method does is splits both x and y strings into their last 3 characters, even though that first '*' in y is supposed to represent 2 characters. How can I make it so that cases like this return a match?

Comment: I swear I've seen this question before...

Comment: I've never asked a question like this, and this is my second time asking a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15733593/961971 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/15780058/961971 look identical to me, just without the full main method to drive it.

Comment: thanks for directing me to those, they do seem to be the exact same as this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to understand the concept of recursion (that is the objective of your homework). The way recursion works is that everytime a function calls itself, the current execution (variables/ execution info) goes onto a stack and sleeps there till the new call finishes.

To solve the problem you have mentioned, lets take a simple example, hello and h@llo. A basic way to solve problem will be that match service call itself again and again till

1. A perfect match is found - return true
2. A failure condition is found- return false
3. In absence of above 2, match calls itself with one character less than the prev call

Something like

Call 1: hello & h@llo// calls match again and present call moves to stack, waits for a reply

Call 2: ello & @llo //matches special character

call 3: llo and llo// perfect match return true to call 2

Back to call 2: receives true from prv call and returns back to call 1

Back to call 1: receives true and returns to main.

Once you understand the concept of recursion stack, solving this problem will be simple

Your final match method will look something like

```
public static boolean match(String x, String y) {

    //if both are empty
    if(x.length()==0 && y.length()==0) return true;

    //if one is empty
    if(x.length()==0 )
    {
        if(y.charAt(0)!='*')
            return false;
        if(y.length()!=1)
            //border line case
            return match(x,y.substring(1));
        else 
            return true;
    }
    if(y.length()==0 )
    {
        if(x.charAt(0)!='*')
            return false;
        if(x.length()!=1)
            //border line case
            return match(y,x.substring(1));
        else 
            return true;
    }   

    //Base case 
    if(x.equals(y) || x.equals("*") || y.equals("*"))
    {

        return true;//we are done as strings are equal
    }


    //we are here that means strings are not equal yet 
    if(x.charAt(0)=='@' || y.charAt(0)=='@' ||x.charAt(0)==y.charAt(0))
    {
        if(x.length()==1 && y.length()==1) return true;//this was the last character
        if(x.length()>1 && y.length()>1)
        {

            //we have single char wild card or char 0 equal,  lets remove the char at 0th location and check again 
            return (match(x.substring(1),y.substring(1)));
        }
    }

    if(x.charAt(0)=='*')
    {
        //this is interesting now, we will need to skip 0..n number of characters till we find matching pattern
        //case 0 chars: he*llo and hello
        if(match(x.substring(1),y)==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        else if (match(x.substring(1),y.substring(1))==true)
        {
            //case 1: he*lo and hello
            return true;
        }           
        else
        {
            //case n chars: h*o and hello
            return (match(x, y.substring(1)));
        }

    }

    if(y.charAt(0)=='*')
    {
        //this is interesting now, we will need to skip 0..n number of characters till we find matching pattern
        //case 0 chars: he*llo and hello
        if(match(y.substring(1),x)==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        else if (match(x.substring(1),y.substring(1))==true)
        {
            //case 1: he*lo and hello
            return true;
        }           
        else
        {
            //case n chars: h*o and hello
            return (match(y, x.substring(1)));
        }

    }
    //nothing worked out
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I for some reason couldn't wrap my head around the * cases, but I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of `recursion` (one of your tags) but not of Java, here is a Scheme implementation that gets all your test cases correct.

```
(define (match s1 s2) ; assumes s1 = string, s2 = pattern
  (let matching ((l1 (string->list s1)) (l2 (string->list s2)))
    (if (null? l1)
        (or (null? l2) (eq? (car l2) #\*)) ; every #\*
        (let ((c1 (car l1))
              (c2 (car l2)))
          (or (and (or (eq? c2 c1)
                       (eq? c2 #\@))
                   (matching (cdr l1) (cdr l2))) ; take one char from l1 and l2
              (and (eq? c2 #\*)
                   (matching (cdr l1) l2)))))))  ; take one char from l1
```

Note, for test cases with `"*l*"` the above gets the right answer but for the wrong reason.  There are others that the above gets wrong (related to `"*"`) but that are not in your test cases.

Comment: Down votes?  Really?  For illustrating recursion in a short concise example.  Two tags are combined with AND or OR?